# Where to upload a reprint (post-print) of my publication?

Tags: publications, online-resource, repository

I used to self-archive papers on my homepage in the institute where I was doing phd. I just noticed that my homepage and the reprints were removed -- that's normal, I'm not working in that institute anymore.

I can legally self-archive these papers. For example, J. Appl. Cryst. [allows authors](http://journals.iucr.org/services/authorrights.html) to post reprints

> on their own personal website, on their employer's website/repository
>   and on free public servers in their subject area.

What are the best "free public servers" to upload electronic reprints?
(IIUC arXiv is for pre-prints rather than post-prints).

Comment: What's wrong with http://www.nieto.pl/?

Comment: @JeffE: nothing wrong, but I'm wondering if there is a dedicated service that makes papers easier to find that one's own website. Although it may not matter, google will index it anyway.

Comment: As Piotr says in his answer, arXiv is definitely not just for pre-prints (it's not even primarily intended for pre-prints).  The arXiv calls them "e-prints" to avoid the issue of whether they are preprints, although this name has not really caught on more broadly.

Comment: arXiv also has that annoying rule that you need to be invited by someone (or whatever they call it). That can be a problem.

Comment: @marcin People search on Google Scholar then they visit you website (see this answer http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/9863/49). So the point is on how it is easy for Google to find it and how  it is likely to stay for a longer time.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Not exactly (I got an account "as it is"), but see http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/4812/whats-arxiv-endorsement-policy (unless you are a crackpot, it shouldn't be hard to know someone (even via a SE site :)), who wants to endorse you).

Comment: @PiotrMigdal Well, you can get an account, but need an endorsement to post. I had problems with the endorse thing. I couldn't find anyone I knew in the relevant areas who actually used arXiv. Apparently contacting to strangers can work, but I didn't try that.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I was lucky enough to not need endorsement to post. So, what is your field, etc (but actually, it may be more for a priv than comments here)?

Comment: @PiotrMigdal I was trying to post in statistics and biomedical (two different papers) if I recall correctly, but I forget the details - it has been some time. We can talk in chat if you want...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8853/discussion-between-piotr-migdal-and-faheem-mitha)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[arXiv](http://arxiv.org/) is not only for preprints (actually, updating after publication is highly encouraged). So if you can self-archive*) *and* you have an intersection with an arXiv discipline, it is the best place to place it.

*) The only objection to post-publication is in case where you are not allowed to self-archive and don't wan't to mess with it.

For other disciplines, see [Preprint services other than arXiv (for other fields)](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/84/preprint-services-other-than-arxiv-for-other-fields).

Or (maybe even better) just - putting them on [GitHub](http://github.com) repository. It is a stable service + makes it easy to upload work with source code (tex + figures) (much alike arXiv, but on GitHub it is more convenient). Just make sure to link the pdf file in the `README.md` and reference it properly (i.e. the full citation, the best with a DOI link) so to have its status clear.

Comment: I don't think this is legally allowed. The Figshare terms of service state that "All publicly stored research outputs are stored under Creative Commons Licenses"; he does not have enough rights left to publish under one. As for Github, I seem to recall that you can only publish open source code there, although I can't find anything specific on the ToS now. A post-published self-archived pdf surely is not open source.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Good point, I've removed the Figshare part. On GitHub it is you who set the license. Open source (i.e. source is visible) does not carry any license _per se_ (AFAIK). Posting PDF without source there, AFAIK, does not differ from posting it on your homepage.

Comment: Will Google pick up and index a paper posted on Github?

Comment: @FaheemMitha If you link it explicitly in `README.md` - I guess it should (all in all, you can search for GitHub repositories). But I haven't tested it in practice (maybe I should?). Do you have any arguments why it shouldn't take it (e.g. some `no-index`/`no-follow`?).

Comment: @PiotrMigdal: No, I've no idea whether the Google indexing would work or not. I don't currently have a good place to put my papers either, but I hadn't thought of using GitHub. Though I'd be more likely to use BitBucket, as I use that already.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Most likely BitBucket is as good as GitHub for this purpose.

Comment: Google seems to pick up PDF files on github just fine: http://www.google.com/search?q=filetype%3Apdf%20site%3Agithub.com

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Well, the acid test would be searching for the title of a paper on GitHub without especially searching GitHub, and seeing if it came up. :-)

Comment: @PiotrMigdal: Thanks for your answer. I've put the papers on Github for now.